# Why is android studio not allowing me to select a locale region?

Tags: android, android-studio, locale

I want to use resource qualifiers to create a locale specific strings.xml file for English (United States) but when in the "New Resource File" window, if I select a language (English) and then select ANY region, the region quickly gets de-selected and thus, only a language specific locale is being allowed.

No error is being shown as well.

[This is the video to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6QhY.jpg)

Android Studio version: 2021.1.1
OS: Windows 11

Comment: Hello, i was not able to reproduce error, could you please add android studio version, os version etc ?

Comment: @jacouille I've added the info

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, I can't reproduce your error on my machine. But I've found a work around for you.

Simply create (with command line, or file explorer) a directory named as you need (for example "values-en-rUS" for en-US local, you can see that directory name on your video just before it unselect itself), and then simply create a file value.xml inside.

[image]

> 2 examples i created inside my res directory

Now, you would be able to find it in your android studio project tab as in my example :

[image]

> results from android studio project window

I know this does not fix your problem, but at least you can work

Comment: Yes, that way I'm able to create those folders but they aren't working as intended. Like I have a text saying **Soccer** in en-rUS file but saying **Football** in the default file. Now, **Soccer** should only be displayed when **English(United States)** selected but it's displayed for any region which has **English** eg. selecting **English(India)** in phone's language settings also shows **Soccer**

Comment: One more thing to add: The text changes to _Football_ if I select any other language eg. french, hindi, etc. It's as if the language "filter" is the only one working

Comment: Maybe you should open a ticket, it certainly is a bug

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look here for bug reports submitting https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs